# number_section yaml-argument: how to check, if it is set manually to true

Tags: r, bookdown, officedown

In `markdown_document2` the `number_section` argument of the yaml is by default set to `true`. For `officedown` I'm searching a way to check the fact, that the user does set the value manually and really wishes to get auto-numbered headlines. `!is.null()` is no option and `isTrue()` is indeed true in either case − default value or manually set.

```
---
title: number_section with rdocx_document
subtitle: how to check, if number_section was set manually
output:
   bookdown::markdown_document2:
     base_format: officedown::rdocx_document
     number_section: FALSE
     fig_caption: TRUE
---

# This is the first Headline &minus; should be auto-numbered

... but only, if the user sets `number_section: TRUE`
```

Comment: Please include a reproducible example.

Comment: @user2554330 I added a rmd-script as reproduceable example for the use with officedown.

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be to change the default value of `number_section` in bookdown to `false`. At the moment the actual code that needs to be adapted is inside of `officedown`. In my version a commented out...

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `bookdown`, but I would guess the best way to do this is to set up your own format.  I don't know if it should replace `bookdown::markdown_document2` or the base format `officedown::rdocx_document`.  This probably requires that you write a package, but it might not need to contain anything but this format function.

Comment: @user2554330 Thank you for the interesting idea. At the moment I forked the whole officedown package and changed the code for rdocx_document. If there were  conditional statements to ensure that "no explicitly set argument" means `false` and otherwise it's `true`, the problem inside the original officedown package would be solved. Or to keep it simple adding `rdocx_document2` to officedown would do the job.

Comment: Sounds like you should try submitting a PR to the main `officedown` repos.

Comment: Infact. I guess I'm gonna try the `rdocx_document2` PR. That should be fine for all users.